# Why is javac not able to typecheck the call site of a static method with a bounded type parameter as return type?

Tags: java, generics, return-type

Why does `javac` not abort with a type error on this code example

```
import java.util.List;

public class StaticMethodWithBoundedReturnType {
    static class Foo {
    }

    static class Bar extends Foo {
    }

    static <F extends Foo> F getFoo(String string) {
        …
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Compiles without error, even though List does not extend Foo.
        List<Integer> list = getFoo("baz");
    }
}
```

Obviously `List` can never be a subtype of `Foo`. And even if there would exists a subtype of `List` which would somehow extend `Foo`, then the assigning of `list` at the call site of `getFoo()` should be invalid. I'm aware of the existence of type erasure. But shouldn't `javac` be able see that the type of `list` does not satisfy the bounded type constraint `extends Foo` and thus fail compilation with a type error?

Why is `javac` not able to typecheck the call site of a static method with a bounded type parameter as return type?

It appears I could get type safety with the following slight modification:

```
import java.util.List;

public class StaticMethodWithBoundedReturnType {
    static class Foo {
    }

    static class Bar extends Foo {
    }

    static <F extends Foo> F getFoo(String string, Class<F> clazz) {
        …
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Does not compile \o/
        List<Integer> list = getFoo("baz", List.class);
    }
}
```

But this requires adding the `Class` parameter to getFoo() which isn't used in the method's body at all. Is there a better way to achieve type safety?

Comment: [similar(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39305730/string-gets-assigned-to-a-list-without-a-compilation-error) [issues(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29670018/why-can-this-generic-method-with-a-bound-return-any-type)

Comment: I guess the return type of (first)`getFoo` is inferred as an Object

Comment: Why do you expect it to fail? There's no obvious type problem here, even if the method is promising magical type casts. The two snippets are roughly the same, although the second one has extra information to use in the method implementation

Comment: Your second one doesn't compile because using `Class<T>` would require that you pass `Integer.class`, not `List.class` (or assign to `List`, not `Integer`). In other words, the problem now is that you supply different, incompatible values for `T`, which is a different problem than your first snippet.

Answer (score 2):

To understand this, we need to understand what the following actually means:

```
static <F extends Foo> F getFoo(String string) {
    return null;
}
```

That says that `getFoo` returns a value of some type that must be inferred from the context in which the call is made.  Furthermore, it makes the constraint, that the inferred type must be a subtype of `Foo`.

Since `null` is assignable to all possible reference types, it is suitable as a return value.  In fact, it is the only possible that may be returned.

To illustrate, try the following variation:

```
import java.util.List;

public class StaticMethodWithBoundedReturnType {
    static class Foo {
    }

    static class Bar extends Foo {
    }

    static <F extends Foo> F getFoo(String string) {
        return new Bar();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Compiles without error, even though List does not extend Foo.
        List<Integer> list = getFoo("baz");
    }
}
```

This gives a compilation error

```
StaticMethodWithBoundedReturnType.java:11: error: incompatible types:
Bar cannot be converted to F
        return new Bar();
               ^
```

You may ask: *Why isn't Bar compatible with F?*.

Answer: because the `F` stands for `( R & ? extends Foo )` where `R` is the type that the result of `getFoo` is assigned to.  And, within `getFoo` re cannot know what `R` will be.  (Indeed, it can be lots of different types!)

In short, the type signature

```
    <F extends Foo> F getFoo(String string)
```

is problematic.  However, consider this:

```
static <F extends Foo> F getFoo(Class<F> clazz) {
    return class.newInstance();
}
```

That is legal, and will return a value that satisfies runtime type safety (locally).  But you will *then* get the expected compilation error if you try to assign it to a `List<Integer>`:

```
StaticMethodWithBoundedReturnType.java:16: error: incompatible types:
inference variable F has incompatible bounds
        List<Integer> list = getFoo(Bar.class);
                                   ^
    equality constraints: Bar
    upper bounds: List<Integer>,Foo
  where F is a type-variable:
    F extends Foo declared in method <F>getFoo(Class<F>)
1 error
```

---

Returning to the example, consider the call:

```
 List<Integer> list = getFoo("baz");
```

That is legal because the *inferred* type for the result is the intersection type `(List<Integer> & ? extends Foo)`.  Indeed, that intersection type is implementable; e.g. as

```
 class Baz extends Bar implements List<Integer> { /* list methods */ }
```

(The fact that there is no implementation in this `Baz` class in our program is immaterial.  There could be one.)

So, we can compile the program.  And when we execute it, `list` will be assigned `null`, which is not a runtime type violation.